# Why doesn't my text be bold when displaying on device screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

My **string.xml**:

```
<!--I try to bold my argument %s, like below:-->
<string name="hello">Hello to: <b>%s</b> !</string>
```

My layout **main.xml**:

```
<LinearLayout
   ...>

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/hello_txt"
     ...
     .../>

</LinearLayout>
```

My **Fragment** class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
  TextView helloTxt;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    helloTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_txt);

  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();

     //pass "Monday" as the argument to my string
     helloTxt.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.hello), "Monday"));

  }
}
```

When I run my app on my device, I got "*Hello to: Monday !*" displaying on screen, but the "**Monday**" is not **bold**, but I used `<b>` in my **string.xml**. Why it is not bold??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

String.xml :

```
<string name="hello">Hello to:  &lt;b>%s&lt;/b>.</string>
```

In your Activity :

```
TextView mytext1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx1);
mytext1.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format(getString(R.string.hello), "Monday")));
```

It Works for me.

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.

Comment: Aha!, the trick is the "&lt;" instead of "<" for <b>. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Html.fromHTML() method

```
String str = HTML.fromHTML(String.format(getString(R.string.hello), "Monday"));
helloTxt.setText(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `html` markup then you need to use `Html.fromHtml`, something like this:

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```